# Django authentications problems - user.save() changes password hash

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I am experiencing an odd authentication problem in Django 1.4.5:

As soon as I call user.save() the password hash changes and does not check successfully against the specified raw password:

```
In [17]: user.check_password('test')
Out[17]: False

In [18]: user.set_password('test')

In [19]: user.check_password('test')
Out[19]: True

In [20]: user.save()

In [21]: user.check_password('test')
Out[21]: False
```

The password is hashed with the pbkdf2_sha256 hasher:

```
In [22]: user.password
Out[22]: 'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$Aj5RbYndelmz$j35cic6UBh/HWnD//7TMfGWEtt7j4+T6970lOezpc1U='
```

So even after creating a super user:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I cannot log in with the credentials specified.

**Why does user.save() change the password hash and how can I solve this issue?**

Comment: It shouldn't be happening, and I can't reproduce it with a newly created 1.4.5 project. Have you modified the User model somehow, or some other part of contrib.auth?

Comment: OK, I found some code that a developer was calling via the pre_save signal. I fixed a bug in this code and now the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found some code that a developer was calling via the pre_save signal. I fixed a bug in this code and now the problem is solved.